# Transferring Excel Data to Unity

Tags: excel, unity-game-engine

I have a large list of data in an excel spreadsheet that I need to transfer a few arrays in my Unity project. I have been looking up a few methods and will likely try out a few of them, but I had another question. Is it possible to transfer Excel data to Unity arrays without an additional plug in or tool? Just with base Unity?

Comment: Have you tried reading in excel files as you would from normal c# and seen what happens?

Answer (score 2):

As @julienkay says, if the excel file is a .csv could be treated as a plain text file, **BUT** what if not?

If you are working with .xlsx I recommend to use `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;`, it's pretty easy to use, but not so easy to get it working in Unity, that's why this [link](https://forum.unity.com/threads/help-with-microsoft-office-interop-excel-in-unity.686398/) could help you!

And this is a simple example on how to use the Interop.Excel methods, this code will create a dictionary filled with the titles and links for the books in this excel:

```
private void Exel()
{
    Dictionary<string, string> linkTitleDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    Application app = new Application();
    Workbook excelWorkbook = app.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\Users\...\SpringerEbooks.xlsx");
    Sheets excelSheets = excelWorkbook.Worksheets;
    string currentSheet = "Table 1";
    Worksheet excelWorksheet = (Worksheet)excelSheets.get_Item(currentSheet);
    //
    for (int i = initialRow; i < finalRow + 1; i++)
    {
        string bookTitle = (string)(excelWorksheet.Cells[i, 2] as Range).Value;
        string bookLink = (string)(excelWorksheet.Cells[i, 5] as Range).Value;
        linkTitleDict.Add(bookLink, bookTitle);
    }
}
```

How the excel looks:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to save your excel file in the .csv format to load that into Unity this is easily achievable without additional plugins, because .csv is essentially just a text file. Just one example on how to parse a .csv file can be found here: https://bravenewmethod.com/2014/09/13/lightweight-csv-reader-for-unity/

If you want to read native excel files (.xlsx) that would be more difficult.