# Faster method to read large CSV file

Tags: c#, csv, unity-game-engine, streamreader

I have a fairly large CSV dataset, around 13.5MB and with approximately 120,000 rows and 13 columns. The code below is the current solution that I have in place.

```
private IEnumerator readDataset()
{
    starsRead = 0;
    var totalLines = File.ReadLines(path).Count();
    totalStars = totalLines - 1;

    string firstLine = File.ReadLines(path).First();
    int columnCount = firstLine.Count(f => f == ',');

    string[,] datasetTable = new string[totalStars, columnCount];

    int lineLength;
    char bufferChar;
    var bufferString = new StringBuilder();
    int column;
    int row;

    using (FileStream fs = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
    using (BufferedStream bs = new BufferedStream(fs))
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(bs))
    {
        string line = sr.ReadLine();
        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            row = 0;
            column = 0;
            lineLength = line.Length;
            for (int i = 0; i < lineLength; i++)
            {
                bufferChar = line[i];
                if (bufferChar == ',')
                {
                    datasetTable[row, column] = bufferString.ToString();
                    column++;
                }
                else
                {
                    bufferString.Append(bufferChar);
                }
            }
            row++;
            starsRead++;
            yield return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Luckily, as I am running this via a Unity coroutine, the program doesn't freeze up, but this current solution takes 31 minutes and 44 seconds to read the entirety of the CSV file.

Is there any other way I can do this? I am trying to target a parse time of less than 1 minute.

Comment: not sure if it'll be faster, but I would try Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel class, if it's faster please tell us!

Comment: @Lotan, from my research on this, there are a lot of limitations. To state a few, this only works on Windows and must require the same Excel version on the client's machine. I might be wrong with this and I am happy to explore this. Please let me know how to use it as I am quite new to it.

Comment: @SidS You're probably right about the limitations. But if you still want to try, here I answered how to use it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61939560/transferring-excel-data-to-unity/61940445#61940445

Comment: Your solution takes 81 milliseconds to read 150000 rows x 13 columns. My file wasn't 13.5MB it was 10MB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic mistake you are making is doing only **1 single line per frame** so you can basically calculate how long you will take for around 60fps:

```
120,000 rows / 60fps = 2000 seconds = 33.3333 minutes
```

due to the `yield return null;` which basically says "Pause the routine, render this frame and continue in the next frame".

---

Of course it would be way faster speaking about absolute time by not using `yield return null` or a Coroutine at all but let the entire thing be parsed in one single go. But then of course it freezes the UI main thread for a moment.

To avoid that the **best** way in my opinion would actually be to move the entire thing in a `Thread`/`Task` and only return the result!

FileIO and string parsing is always quite slow.

---

However, I think you could already speed it up a lot by simply using a [`StopWatch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch) like

```
...

var stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
stopWatch.Start();

// Use the last frame duration as a guide for how long one frame should take
var targetMilliseconds = Time.deltaTime * 1000f;

while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    ....

    // If you are too long in this frame render one and continue in the next frame
    // otherwise keep going with the next line
    if(stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds > targetMilliseconds)
    {
        yield return null;
        stopWatch.Restart();
    }
}
```

This allows to work off multiple lines within one frame while trying to keep a 60fps frame-rate. You might want to experiment a bit with it to find a good trade off between frame-rate and duration. E.g. maybe you can allow it to run with only 30fps but importing faster since like this it can handle more rows in one frame.

---

In general I wouldn't read "manually" through each byte/char. Rather use the builtin methods for that like e.g. `String.Split`.

I am actually using a bit more advanced [`Regex.Matches`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches) since if you export a CSV from Excel it allows special cases like one cell itself containing a `,` or other special characters like e.g. linebreaks(!).

Excel does it by wrapping the cell in `"` in this case. Which adds a second special case, namely a cell itself containing a `"`.

The `Regex.Marches` is quite complex of course and slow itself but covers these special cases. (See also [Basic CSV rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#Basic_rules) for more detailed explanation on special cases)

If you know the format of your CSV well and don't need it you could/should probably rather just stick to

```
var columns = row.Split(new []{ ','});
```

to split it always just on `,` which would run faster.

```
private const char Quote = '\"';
private const string LineBreak = "\r\n";
private const string DoubleQuote = "\"\"";

private IEnumerator readDataset(string path)
{
    starsRead = 0;
    // Use the last frame duration as a guide how long one frame should take
    // you can also try and experiment with hardcodd target framerates like e.g. "1000f / 30" for 30fps
    var targetMilliseconds = Time.deltaTime * 1000f;
    var stopWatch = new Stopwatch();

    // NOTE: YOU ARE ALREADY READING THE ENTIRE FILE HERE ONCE!!
    // => Instead of later again read it line by line rather re-use this file content
    var lines = File.ReadLines(path).ToArray();
    var totalLines = lines.Length;
    totalStars = totalLines - 1;

    // HERE YOU DID READ THE FILE AGAIN JUST TO GET THE FIRST LINE ;)
    string firstLine = lines[0];

    var firstLineColumns = GetColumns(firstLine);

    columnCount = firstLineColumns.Length;

    var datasetTable = new string[totalStars, columnCount];

    stopWatch.Start();
    for(var i = 0; i < totalStars; i++)
    {
        string row = lines[i + 1];

        string[] columns = GetColumns(row);

        var colIndex = 0;
        foreach(var column in columns)
        {
            if(colIndex >= columnCount - 1) break;
            datasetTable[i, colIndex] = colum;
            colIndex++;
        }

        starsRead = i + 1;

        // If you are too long in this frame render one and continue in the next frame
        // otherwise keep going with the next line
        if (stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds > targetMilliseconds)
        {
            yield return null;
            stopWatch.Restart();
        }
    }
}

private string[] GetColumns(string row)
{
    var columns = new List<string>();

    // Look for the following expressions:
    // (?<x>(?=[,\r\n]+))           --> Creates a Match Group (?<x>...) of every expression it finds before a , a \r or a \n (?=[...])
    // OR |
    // ""(?<x>([^""]|"""")+)""      --> An Expression wrapped in single-quotes (escaped by "") is matched into a Match Group that is neither NOT a single-quote [^""] or is a double-quote
    // OR |
    // (?<x>[^,\r\n]+)),?)          --> Creates a Match Group (?<x>...) that does not contain , \r, or \n
    var matches = Regex.Matches(row, @"(((?<x>(?=[,\r\n]+))|""(?<x>([^""]|"""")+)""|(?<x>[^,\r\n]+)),?)", RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);

    foreach (Match match in matches)
    {
        var cleanedMatch = match.Groups[1].Value == "\"\"" ? "" : match.Groups[1].Value.Replace("\"\"", Quote.ToString());
        columns.Add(cleanedMatch);
    }

    // If last thing is a `,` then there is an empty item missing at the end
    if (row.Length > 0 && row[row.Length - 1].Equals(','))
    {
        columns.Add("");
    }

    return columns.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Amazing! I used a stopwatch just like your answer and now my program only takes around 35 seconds to load up the dataset. Threads would be a great option but unfortunately, Unity3D doesn't work with it.

Comment: Also, multiplying Time.deltaTime with 1000f and settings this to targetMilliseconds gives another substantial loading time improvement. Bringing the total time to only 5 seconds!

Comment: Oh crap yeah it should be multiplication ofcourse :D

Comment: Thank you so much, great answer!

Comment: its hard to relate this to the q and a, was data modified in the q

Comment: @Seabizkit what do you mean?

Comment: @SidS btw this is just c# and Unity ofcourse can be used with Threads :) There are ways of how to wait for a result from a thread within the Unity main thread without blocking it ;) One is e.g. a pattern like the [Units main thread dispatcher](https://github.com/PimDeWitte/UnityMainThreadDispatcher/blob/master/UnityMainThreadDispatcher.cs) (though in my eyes it requires some refactoring ^^)

Comment: @Seabizkit Downvote is very unnecessary and your reasoning is completely incoherent.

Comment: @derHugo im trying to understand how this was marked as the answer to the question, you talk about measuring aka with stopwatch, and then start talking in the context of unity with relation to frames. was trying to understand how this was the answer to reading reading a large csv faster..., ps you have you down-vote story all messed up i did not down-vote. i'm actually trying understand.

Comment: @SidS first of all, I did not my down-vote! second what , im trying to understand how doing the same thing +- but showing a way of measuring code and talking about frames, is the answer to speeding up reading a csv... there seem to be a disconnect for me between the answer given and the question, hense i was asking if info in the question was removed.. that i cant see which would explains the possible disconnect. or what part of the answer, was the reason it was "slow"... what in this answer is the reason your code was "sub optimal"

Comment: @Seabizkit I never said the downvote came from you ;) I just thought maybe the one could explain. The reason why the StopWatch helps here is: OP had a `yield return null` for each and every line of the file. This means after every line that Coroutine was interrupted, a frame rendered and then in the next frame the next line was parsed. As explained on the top this means that for 120000 lines in the file you will always need 120000 frames to finish. Using the StopWatch it allows to parse multiple lines in one single frame without making the frame take too long so a user would notice

Comment: for kick would the answer then be remove `yield return null;`, is the reason yield is used... is to relief the UI (main) thread... so it still in interact-able? if so then i can understand but you make it way more complected to get. but well done if that what you were saying. If that was the problem... then it was never about speed.... it was about making it smooth.. which are to different things.. so its slow cozs the way it was made to be smooth is of bad implementation...OK got it now.. but can you see the disconnect, the reading could be on separate thread, made async read once put in mem

Comment: @Seabizkit if you look at the bottom of the answer I mentioned as well that of course it would be better to do large FileIO and string operations on a separate Thread/Task and let the main thread wait for the result. But yes the main reason is simply that `yield return null` means: "Pause" the routine, render one frame and continue from here in the next frame. And yes it is about speed because that is what made the whole import a lot slower than it needed to be. Ofcourse if you entirely remove the `yield` it would be faster but block the UI main thread for a moment - OP wanted to avoid that

Comment: @Seabizkit I rephrased/restructured the answer in hope to be more clear about it now, please check it out

Comment: @SidS Hey I just noted another huge impact! You actually are using `File.ReadLines` two times before just to get some simple information! This is also extremely inefficient. In the end you have read the entire file 3 times! I changed my answer to rather simply re-use the lines already returned by `File.ReadLines` .. and then there is also no need to use any of the later used Streams anymore! It should be way faster now and not block the first frame

Comment: aka 1 of reason its "slow" is you do var `totalLines = File.ReadLines(path).Count();`  which actually is the entire file in one go and then just use count. you could of done `totalLines = File.ReadLines(path);` and looped over the lines in mem @SidS, ps my biggest thing is no where does it say this is done on the main thread and you want smoothness.

Comment: I used IEnumerator to free up the UI. as @Jesús López had also said in his answer below, I am reading through the file multiple times which is inefficient. I will be changing this.

Answer (score 4):

What about this?

```
private IEnumerable<string[]> ReadCsv(string path)
{
    using (var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None, 64 * 1024, FileOptions.SequentialScan)) 
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(fs))
    {
        string line = reader.ReadLine();
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            yield return line.Split(',');
        }
    }
}
```

It should be faster because:

- It reads the file only once, you read it twice.
- FileOptions.SequentialScan helps operating system to cache it more efficiently.
- Larger buffer reduce system calls.

It is also more efficient in memory terms since it doesn't keep the entire information in memory. Do you need to keep all information in memory, or you can process it line by line?

Comment: OP is using an `IEnumerator` in order to run the code as a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) which in Unity is used to run code "smooth" without blocking the main thread too much. Ofcourse the fastest thing would be to run it in one go but then the application will notable freeze for this frame.

Comment: @derHugo wrapped method in coroutine

Comment: That Coroutine makes no sense at all .. if you only yield in the end it is the same as simply execute it as a normal method -> blocks the main thread in the same way

Answer (score 1):

30 minutes is insanely slow!

There seems to be a few issues:

- `bufferString` never gets cleared. See below for an updated version. Clearing it down allows the code to run in <1s on my machine with a 23MB 130,000 row input file.
- `row` gets reset at the endof each loop iteration, meaning that only `datasetTable[0, col]` gets populated. If this is intentional you can probably simplify some of the startup code.
- As people have mentioned, code to *correctly* parse CSV is insanely tricky, but if you can be confident of the format of your input files this should be ok.

```
                        if (bufferChar == ',')
                        {
                            datasetTable[row, column] = bufferString.ToString();
                            column++;
                            bufferString.Clear(); // <-- Add this line
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            bufferString.Append(bufferChar);
                        }
```

Comment: Thanks! I completely overlooked these two errors. I added the bufferString.Clear(); and I've moved row=0; to outside the while loop

Comment: No problem. Glad to have helped. :-). I'm not familiar with unity, but combining this with the solution from @derHugo sounds like a good idea.

Comment: Indeed, @derHugo's answer, loading times has reduced to only 5 seconds

Answer (score -2):

You may have a memory issue.  Open Task Manager while code is running to see is you are reaching the max amount of memory.

Try following :

```
        private void readDataset()
        {

            List<List<string>> datasetTable = new List<List<string>>(); ;


            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path))
            {
                string line = sr.ReadLine();  //skip header row
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    datasetTable.Add(line.Split(new char[] { ',' }).ToList());
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: This is _not_ a stable way to read from CSV (see e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#Basic_rules) for reasons). Better use a well-tested 3rd-party library.

Comment: That is an absolute ridiculous statement to say a Net library method is not stable.  Why use a library when Net already has a good library.  Especially when OP has a very large file and want to speed up the time.  Adding additional library adds over head a uses more memory and and slows down code.

Comment: Not entirely sure how this handles columns, could you please explain further?

Comment: You have a comma separated file (CSV)  So the Add with simply put each split column into the datasetTable like your posted code.

Comment: @jdweng you should rather use a more complex regex. If you export e.g. a MicrosoftExcel table to CSV it wraps special cases in `""`. You can e.g. have a CSV line containing commas itself like `SOMEID, "Well, hello there!", "Something containing \"quotations\" itself"`

Comment: @jdweng, to parse the entire dataset, my solution took 31m 44s and your's took 21m 15s. This is a large improvement, although not near my target of under 1 minute, to would be great if you could tell me what the bottleneck is and how your solution is about 10 minutes quicker

Comment: As I said look at task manager and check the memory usage.  When you use all the memory, swap space is used which is on hard drive and slows program down.  Try a machine with more memory and check speed.  Also if file is not on c drive ( a remote machine) the reading over network could slow down operation.  My changes is using only one stream which I think used less memory.  You solution had more than one stream opened.